# Allow for 1 "JS generated" checkbox to be checked at any time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How I am able to get js to allow for only 1 checkbox in a group of checkboxes to be selected at any time. I have completed this as per code below for checkboxes that I have created in html code, *however this code (see my attempt below) does not work on checkboxes that have be generated by JS*. any help with this

Note in the code at the very bottom, that many checkboxes are created by JS as part of a for loop function so the  `on('click', function(evt)` needs to suits the `len` variable for this to work

**Html Code:**

```
<tr>
    <td>Prior to work on Site- Submit Telstra Building Works Permit in TCSS</td>
    <td>        
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <input type="checkbox" name="F06_yes_1" id="F06_yes_1" data-mini="true" class = "f06_1" />
    <label for="F06_yes_1">Yes</label>                              
    <input type="checkbox" name="F06_no_1" id="F06_no_1" data-mini="true" class = "f06_1"/>
    <label for="F06_no_1">No</label>                                
    <input type="checkbox" name="F06_na_1" id="F06_na_1" data-mini="true" class = "f06_1" />
    <label for="F06_na_1">N/A</label>                               
    </fieldset>                             
    </td>
    <td><input name="F06-c-1" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
```

**Working js Code:**

```
$('input.f06_1').on('click', function(evt) {
    if ($('.f06_1:checked').length > 1) {
        $('input.f06_1').not(this).prop('checked', false).checkboxradio("refresh");
    }

});
```

**Code for checkboxes created by js:**

```
table_asset.append(
'<tr>\
    <td><input name="asset_description_'+ (len+1)+'" type="text"  value="' + key + '" /></td> \
    <td><input name="asset_cost_'+ (len+1)+'" type="text" value="' + formatter.format(data[item][key]) + '" onkeydown="return false"/></td> \
    <td>\
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"> \
            <input type="checkbox" name="asset_allocation_capex_'+ (len+1)+'" id="asset_allocation_capex_'+ (len+1)+'" data-mini="true" ' + capex_checked_var + ' class = "capex_opex_'+ (len+1)+'" /> \
            <label for="asset_allocation_capex_'+ (len+1)+'">Capex</label> \
            <input type="checkbox" name="asset_allocation_opex_'+ (len+1)+'" id="asset_allocation_opex_'+ (len+1)+'" data-mini="true" ' + opex_checked_var + ' class = "capex_opex_'+ (len+1)+'" /> \
            <label for="asset_allocation_opex_'+ (len+1)+'">Opex</label>\
        </fieldset>\
    </td>\
    <td><input name="asset_number_'+ (len+1)+'" type="text" value=" ' + asset_number_var + ' "/></td> \
    <td><select name="asset_desc_' + (len+1)+'" id="test" data-mini="true" ' +  asset_type + '</select> </td> \
    <td style="display:none;" > <input  name="type_'+ (len+1)+'" type="text" value="design"/></td>\
</tr>'  
);

                                                );
```

Comment: If you take a look at some other questions you'll notice that there are 2 buttons: `Run Code Snippet` and   `Copy Snippet to Answer`. Please use the button that has the brackets <>. I know you don't like doing it by looking at your profile, but give it a try, thanks. It's already more difficult to answer a question with an easy solution you don't want (i.e. `type=radio`)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want one option selectable, you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: Thanks, but i want to use the checkbox from jquery mobile as i have implemented this throughout my page